# The verb "see" can be ditransitive?

Tags: ditransitive-verbs

I can't find ditransitive *see* on dictionaries and websites.
However, GPT chat answers *see* can be ditransitive with the examples below.

1. I saw him the movie.
2. She saw her friends some great views during their trip.
3. She saw me the information I needed.

As I couldn't fully trust GPT, I wanted to make it clear if the answer is right.
How about these sentences? make sense?

Comment: They make no sense. The verb you need is _showed_, not _saw_.

Comment: GPT chat (or any other AI chatbot) is NOT a good source of English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are grammatical errors by the AI.